# How can I rsync/scp files/folders among EC2 servers?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, private-key

I tried to execute scp/rsync command between two of my EC2 servers but I got the error as be low snapshot.

Normally when I `ssh connect` to my servers via PuTTY, I need to attach a private key. So what I can guess is that the command is requiring the keys.

How can I add the key in the command?

[image]

Comment: This may be helpful but I'm not sure https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=404010

Answer (score 2):

[man scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) would display an option `-i`:

```
  -i identity_file
         Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for RSA authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to ssh(1).
```

Since the option is passed to ssh (as noted above), it can be passed to `rsync`: `-e "ssh -i /path/to/private/key"`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an edit on my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395375/create-a-path-from-lines-in-a-file-on-the-unix-command-line/16395410#16395410 . I don't know why it was rejected. Anyway, I updated it and now it is fine.