# create a path from lines in a file on the unix command line

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I want to build a basic Java class path in a bash script.

This command works out all the jar files to go in my path:

```
find ~/jars | grep \.jar$
```

This lists all the jar files I want on my path, one per line.

How can I join together these lines so they are on one line, separated by `:` and put that into a variable I can use in my script when I invoke Java?

E.g.:

```
JARS=`find ~/jars | grep \.jar$`
#### somehow make JARS into one line with : between entries
java -cp $JARS ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe it and with sed change new line for `,`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/:/g'
```

All together,

```
find ~/jars | grep \.jar$ | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/:/g'
```

You can also do it with `tr`, although it leaves a trailing colon ([glenn jackman comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395375/create-a-path-from-lines-in-a-file-on-the-unix-command-line/16395410?noredirect=1#comment23508470_16395410)):

```
find ~/jars | grep \.jar$ | tr '\n' ':'
```

Based on [SED: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1983854)

Comment: the `tr` solution leaves you with a trailing colon

Answer (score 2):

if you have already used `find`, you don't need the pipe.

find has `-regex` and `-name` option, also has `printf` available:

You could try this for your requirement:

```
find ~/jars -name "*.jar" -printf"%p "
```

I didn't test, but it would output all jars with full path, space separated.

Comment: Good one! Also, would it be possible to have a couple of downvotes for tag suggestions? I want to cancel two I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested : bash-alias and commands-unix

Comment: @fedorqui I don't even know SO has this function. :D no idea how to do it.. sorry.

Comment: Haha, just go to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/synonyms and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unix/synonyms and up/downvote. If you want, of course! Everything is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Answer (score 1):

```
jars=($(find ~/jars -type f -name \*.jar))   # save paths into array
classpath=$(IFS=:; echo "${jars[*]}")   # convert to colon-separated
java -cp "$classpath" ...               # and use it
```